# Instance of 'StripeConfigException'

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I want to intigrate stripe payment method but i am facing error.I am unable to show paymentsheet.Also when i click on pay button this error happened
**Instance of 'StripeConfigException'**
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(21470): Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10020; state: ENABLED
I/ForceDarkHelperStubImpl(21470): setViewRootImplForceDark: false for , reason: AppDarkModeEnable
I/ForceDarkHelperStubImpl(21470): setViewRootImplForceDark: false for , reason: AppDarkModeEnable
I/ForceDarkHelperStubImpl(21470): setViewRootImplForceDark: false for , reason: AppDarkModeEnable

```
Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            intpayment(email: "email);
            },
          child: Text("Pay20\$"),
        ),
      ),
```

Function

```
Future<void> intpayment(
      {required String email, required double amount})async{
    try{
      final response= await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents")
          ,body:{
            "receipt_email": email,
            "amount": amount.toInt().toString(),
            "currency": "usd"
          },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'key',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
      );
      final jsonresponse=jsonDecode(response.body);      Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonresponse['paymentIntent'],
        merchantDisplayName: 'Zohaib',
        customerId: jsonresponse['customer'],
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonresponse['ephemeralKey'],
      ));
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "payment successfully",
      );
    }
    catch(e){
      if (e is StripeException) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Stripe error $e",
        );
      }
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "$e",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, );
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post the error message a bit more clearly

Comment: When click on pay button it show toast meassage instance of stripe exception